# Python: abrir archivo txt en carpeta distinta

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo

Tengo la siguiente jerarquia

```
> Project
>        App1
>               folder1
>                      main.py
>        App2
>               folder1
>               folder2
>                      file.txt
```

Deseo abrir file.txt desde main.py pero por defecto la función "open()" busca en el directorio del archivo y los subdirectorios del mismo. ¿Cómo haría para poder leer file.txt desde main.py sin necesidad de mover archivos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente pude realizar lo que deseaba, en la carpeta de static cree una carpeta tmp la cual sería dejada con permisos 777, así podían ser accedible donde sea.

Cabe destacar que como usaba django con python se complicaba el uso de

```
with open("../../App2/folder2/file.txt", "r") as f:
```

por tanto inicié una variable en settings con la ruta a los archivos que serían modificados por los archivos views.py de cada aplicación de django.

```
file = open(settings.AJAX_FILES+"data.txt","w",encoding='utf-8')
```

El uso de encoding no tiene que ver con la pregunta pero igual lo dejo puesto por una falla que se me presento para presentar los textos del archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente pásale a `open` como primer argumento la [**ruta relativa**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruta_(inform%C3%A1tica)#Ruta_relativa) al archivo desde `main.py`, en tu caso sería algo así:

```
with open("../../App2/folder2/file.txt", "r") as f:
    # Resto de código aquí
```

Solo hay que tener en cuenta el significado de los puntos:

- `.` (*dot*) hace referencia al directorio actual.
- `..` (*double dot*) nos permite hacer referencia al directorio padre del actual.

Por lo tanto `../` nos posiciona en `App1` y `../../` en `Project`.

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla estoy usando Python 3.5.4 junto a Django 1.11. en views.py llamo al archivo para ser escrito con 'w', el archivo esta en static/ajax/data/file.txt. sabiendo que static esta en el mismo nivel que testApp que contiene views.py entonces "../static/ajax/data/file.txt" debería localizar el archivo, pero lamentablemente no lo hace.

Answer (score 0):

para poder abrir el archivo .txt puedes utilizar lo siguiente

```
def main():
    f = open("Tu ruta")# ejemplo C:\Users\97254\Documents\VisualStudioCode\Test-1\pages\python\english\level1
    for linea in f:
        print linea
    f.close()
main()
```

la ruta tiene que se cargada al reves C:/Users/97254/Documents/VisualStudioCode/Test-1/pages/python/english/level1